# How to access the multiple nib(table view cells) in a Table view

Tags: ios, swift4.2

[Xib File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQm8U.png)

How to access the multiple tableview cells from one xib file in tableview cell

**Following error**:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'invalid nib registered for identifier (Identifier0) - nib must contain exactly one top level object which must be a UITableViewCell instance'

Comment: What the message says - "nib must contain exactly one top level object..." . Break out your XIB into multiple XIB's

Comment: You are trying to add more cells in table view cell xib file. That should only contain a single cell.

Comment: But ....Need to access Multiple  NIB's from The same XIB

Comment: Show some code. How are you registering the nib?

Comment: 1.aTableview.register(UINib(nibName: "multiplecell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "\(stringconcate)")


2. let cell :multiplecell =    tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "\(stringconcate)") as! multiplecell